# executeJavascript in Vaadin Testbench

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-testbench

when I try to get via UI.getCurrent().getPage() to executeJs , it says getPage() (or something above is null). How can I execute Javascript Commands in Testbench then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a TestBench test you can use `executeScript(script, args);` to execute Javascript

You can find some extra information in [TestBench docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/tools/testbench/low-level-element-interactions/#executing-javascript)